# Creating a playlist from my own media library

Tags: html5-video

Hi I'm trying to build my first website where users can play any video from my media library which has 14000 videos in it. If I put a link to the library is there a way that users can access various videos to create their own playlist of say up to 250 videos that will either play sequentially or give them the oportunity to play randomly or maybe the option of rearranging the order that they play in html5 video oh and the media library is on a separate host to the website host. Planning on doing my own hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit too vague.

Do you really plan to make all this yourself? If so you are in for a lot of work, serving video requires transcoding, storage, bandwidth, probably CDN.

You might want to think about using sites like youtube or vimeo. or perhaps a service like VidMeUp (http://vidmeup.com)